# Programmatically generating many Tagged PDFs with XeLaTex

Tags: xetex, truetype, tagged-pdf

Is it possible to create a tagged PDF with XeLaTex or any other Tex Engine? 
(I need to be able to use TrueType fonts).

Furthermore I need to create tagged PDFs of around 70 Books so doing it manually is no option.

Answer (score 1):

Tagged PDF is a pervasive technology in all but the oldest PDF standards.  It is the means that all 'semantics' of PDFs is modelled, and it is the extra-sauce that PDFs bring over the Postscript graphics description language that the PDF standards build on.

If you use any of the following with `xelatex`, you will be generating PDFs with tags:

1. Chapters and sections - these correspond to bookmarks in the generated PDF, which is represented using tags;
2. Hyperlinks - likewise;
3. TrueType and OpenType fonts - the characters are tagged so that they are not just raw pictorial representations, but have their glyph and its place in a word or sentence defined.  Without this, it is impossible to cut-and-paste from PDFs, a problem seen with PDFs that use older, Postscript fonts that lack this metadata;
4. Embedded media and dynamic elements - the parameters and scripting for all dynamic elements are controlled using tagging and embedded Javascript.

Comment: I have no problem cutting and pasting text from PDFs using type1 fonts produced with pdfTeX. In fact, none of the features you list are specific to XeTeX. pdfTeX supports all of them. If you turn your generated PDF into postscript and rasterise it, you'll lose the copy-paste functionality. But that has nothing to do with the fonts you use.

Comment: @cfr You are quite correct that Pdftex also uses tagging, although the way that fonts are handled in Pdftex is very different, since Pdftex uses the TFM representation. I'm not sure I understand the point about you rasterising: if you do that, you won't be using fonts.

Comment: Exactly. But that's the only way I know to kill the copy-paste functionality - otherwise, that works fine for me. (The exception is using oldstyle figures.) It just isn't true that it 'is impossible to cut-and-paste from PDFs' which use type1 fonts.